# Run APK in an Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10, android-emulator

I have an .APK file that I want to run in an APK Emulator on Windows 10.

I currently don't have any Emulator installed - I tried to install and run Android Studio, but each time I try to run it, I get this error (translated from Danish):

```
The program could not start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the program.
```

I've tried to remove and re-install Android Studio but same error. I also tried to restart the computer and even shut down and start PC again from scratch + re-install, but same error always no matter what I do (arrrrgh!!!!)

So I cannot use Android Studio...

Instead, I've tried these other Emulators:

- ApkOnline (not working for me)
- BlueStacks (cannot download due to F-Secure blocking it)
- LD Player (cannot download due to F-Secure blocking it)
- ARChon (Chrome refuses to add this in my browser and just removes it after adding it)
- Bliss OS (cannot download due to F-Secure blocking it)

Is there another Emulator that you recommend to use on Windows ?

Please notice, my PC is managed by my administrator and thus, I don't have administrator permissions etc. on my PC.

My PC does have Intel VT-x enabled in BIOS.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What's this "F-Secure" ? Can't you disable it ? Or use VPN as workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this issue is related to Microsoft Visual C++, .NET Framework or Direct X.

Can you confirm you have these installed and/or updated.

Comment: I have a bunch of MS Visual C++ installed already. I tried to repair them or even re-install, but every time the installer stucks on "Processing" and "Initializing" and never completes., so this does not work either ...

I have .NET Framework 4.8 + Direct X version 12 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to develop my app in Xamarin instead.

Comment: Since this is not really an answer applicable to everyone, you should have posted this in comments and not as answer.